# Сказочные персонажи в тексте

Tags: общие-вопросы

"В гости к детишкам пришла бабушка-обжорка" или "Ребят посетили пираты"...
Как в таком случае пишутся сказочные герои? Кавычки/заглавные буквы/никак не выделять?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Настя, а что у вас за герои такие? "Бабушка-обжорка" очень смахивает на личное имя. 
Поэтому "В гости к детишкам пришла Бабушка Обжорка" (если "бабушка" - часть имени), и  "... пришла бабушка Обжорка", если Обжорка - личное имя бабушки. Не силен я в этих персонажах, а в сети нет упоминаний.

Если же имеется в виду игрушка типа ваньки-встаньки или деда-мороза, то через дефис и со строчной, как у вас и написано.

Что касается второго примера, то там вообще никаких имен нет, значит и вариантов нет. У вас написано корректно.

Comment: Нарицательные имена пишутся со строчной.Вряд ли можно отнести бабушка-обжорка к личному имени.

Comment: Знаете, "нарицательные имена" это именно нарицательные имена. А имена просто - это подразумеваются имена собственные.

Comment: Дополню ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Имена героев (-дополнение к ответу. нарицательные имена сущ.) в середине текста пишутся со строчной и без кавычек.

Comment: Спасибо. ))

Comment: Серж, господь с вами...
С каких пор ***имена*** пишутся со ***строчной***?

Comment: То есть, хотите сказать, дед-мороз надо писать со строчной буквы? за что ж так его? Он же не нарицательный, он же один такой!